# High level of what I will need to do to port ReactiveMongo scala to use cats effects?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, cats-effect

Is it correct to say that if I wanted to use ReactiveMongo in something like http4s I will have to wrap all the Future calls that ReactiveMongo returns in a Cats IO effect?

At a high level, what are the steps I would need to incorporate ReactiveMongo into http4s?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cats Effect provides `Async` typeclass which let you translate some callback (e.g. Future's `onComplete`) into `F`. An [example from documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/async.html#async):

```
import cats.effect.{IO, Async}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

val apiCall = Future.successful("I come from the Future!")

val ioa: IO[String] =
  Async[IO].async { cb =>
    import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

    apiCall.onComplete {
      case Success(value) => cb(Right(value))
      case Failure(error) => cb(Left(error))
    }
 }

ioa.unsafeRunSync()
```

Actually, `Async[F]` evan has a method allowing to lift Future to async: `Async[F].fromFuture(Sync[F].defer(future))` (`Future` is wrapped in IO as its creation is side-effecting, and triggers eager computation).

However, if you are fixed on using `cats.effect.IO` specifically you can simply use `IO.fromFuture(IO(future))`.

You would have to use this (or some utility delegating to this) everywhere you need to translate Future into IO (or other F).